# System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority

Tags: wcf, ssl

I am getting below error while trying to call webservice through UAT environment. However on my local it is working properly.  I see some comment as it might be due to dummy cert but could not get the answer so posting it here . Also i am beginner to WCF . 
Please let me know how can i fix this .

what will be impact on production if i trust all by

```
//Trust all certificates
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

error says -
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority . ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

binding is

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="GLEditServiceSOAP" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

also wonder how it is working on my localhost.

Comment: Did you try adding the server's certificate in trusted certificate store?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this post [here](http://blog.randomdust.com/index.php/2010/10/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel/). As mentioned in the post, returning always True in the certificate validation is safe if you trust the URL with SSL or if all of the components are hosted inside you company's intranet.

Comment: it is not, as certificate validation is used to verify that you are talking to a trusted endpoint. If you ignore that, you could just be talking with a man in the middle without knowing